# $('option').mousedown event does not work in few cases

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using $('option').mousedown function to allow multiple selections for my multiple select list.

It works when the multiple select list is created onload of a page.

But it does not work for the multiple select list that was built using javascript function.

Following is my mousedown event code

```
       $('option').mousedown(function(e) {// alert('dsds');
           e.preventDefault();  
           $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);

          return false;
      });
```

Following is the list I build using javascript.

```
      $.each(vellalarSubCastList, function(j, option) {

        var $option = $("<option>", {text: option.name, value: option.id});
        $option.appendTo($indiaSubCastes);
     });
```

Comment: Some browsers do not support mouseevents on option elements.

Answer (score 2):

Very possible you are attaching the "mousedown" event BEFORE you are generating the list of options. Try calling it after the list is generated.

Alternatively, have you looked into just using the "multiple" attribute?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Or just using a plugin like https://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ting Sung that you are attaching the handler before creating the `option`s.  You can only attach an handler to a element that already exists in the DOM.

This might be simply fixed by changing the order in your code if the list is generate once as the page loads.  Otherwise you should use a delegated handler, like this:

```
  $('select').on('mousedown' ,'option' ,function(e) {// alert('dsds');
       e.preventDefault();  
       $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);

      return false;
  });
```

The handler is attached to the `select` element, but is triggered by a `mousedown` on any child `option` element.  This second parameter filters which child elements will receive the event in the first parameter.  And this works regardless of when they are added to the DOM.

If the `select` is also generated dynamically, and you cannot attach the handler after this, you can attach it to the `div` or whatever other element you are attaching you list to.

This way is also recommended in general as you only need to attach one handler per `select` list.  Using `$('option')` will mean a separate handler being attached to every single `option` in the document.  Whilst this is okay with smaller lists, it is less efficient as they get longer.

Comment: Thanks. Your ($('select').on('mousedown' ,'option' ) works for me. But only issue is the options i select are not shown as highlighted.                             Please hep.......

Comment: There was a slight typo in the code (no need for an opening parenthesis before the function anyway, but there was no matching one after) but taking that out it works for me.  Does this example work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/gv4qvxr0/